# Do not post SelectList with Knockout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm running an ASP.net MVC4 application with Knockout.

I have a generic script that posts my Knockout Forms.

I need to optimize the data sent to the server, because when i post my Knockout ViewModel, SelectList with all items are posted too!

Example Server ViewModel :

`Public Class FooViewModel
     Public Property Bar As String
     Public Property Products As List(Of SelectListItem)
 End Class`

The JS code to convert my Knockout ViewModel to JSON

```
var data = ko.toJSON(viewModel);
```

data variable contains all products items and that's not very optimized.

I found this code (which work) :

```
viewModel.toJSON = function () {
        var copy = ko.toJS(this);
        // remove any unneeded properties           
        delete copy.Products;            
        return copy;
    }
```

But I need a ***generic*** solution ... ! And here I don't see how i can make it generic ...

A quick and dirty solution would be to add a suffix on every array properties like "_NoPost" and then loop and delete every property that has this suffix, but it smells ... bad :/

Any thoughts ?

Comment: why cant you just try like this `ko.toJSON(this,products)` if you just want to pass products array instead of total viewModel data .

Comment: Hello and thanks for trying.
1°) It's the inverse, i don't want the products array
2°) I'd like a generic way of doing that. Algorithm sentence would look like "Send data to server except all SelectList"
Because the script posting data isn't aware of which array properties he has to ignore. 
Am i clear or should i add some details in my question ?

Comment: How do you mean "generic"? You mean Vanilla JS instead of Knockout? If so, you're actually asking for a vanilla JS rewrite of the Knockout mapping plugin or the Knockout `ko.toJS` function.. Also, why not exclude the properties in the call to `ko.toJSON` immediately so you can retrieve a clean object from your DB (instead of in the `ko.toJS` call)??

Comment: I mean "generic" : put a flag or something on a property to ignore it a posting data to server. Instead of deleting each property for each viewModel that has to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one option is to separate your form data from your lookup data like the following.  This will allow you to get hold of only your form data when you need to post it to the server.

```
Public Class FormViewModel
     Public Property Bar As String
End Class

Public Class FooViewModel
     Public Property FormData As FormViewModel
     Public Property Products As List(Of SelectListItem)
End Class
```

Which will allow you to

```
var data = ko.toJSON(viewModel);
$post(url, data.FormData, function(d){...});
```

In your HTML you will also have to include the FormData as part of the variable i.e.

```
<input data-bind="value: FormData.Bar">
```

**EDIT**

Based on your feedback you can use the following function to construct a "clean" object for you.  The idea is to pass in the original JSON object as well as a mapping object which will indicate which of the properties should be excluded/left behind:

```
function MapJson(obj, map) {

    if (obj == undefined)
        return;

    map = map || {};
    var ret = {};

    for (var prop in obj) {

        if (map[prop] != undefined && map[prop] == false)
            continue;

        if (typeof obj[prop] !== "object")
            ret[prop] = obj[prop];
        else {
            if (map.constructor == Array) {
                ret[prop] = MapJson(obj[prop], map[0]);
            }
            else
                ret[prop] = MapJson(obj[prop], map[prop]);
        }

    }

    return ret;
}
```

You can then use it like this - by setting the property's value to *false* it will be excluded from the data.  The sample shows how to block both an array within a child object as well as an array within an array:

```
var obj = {
    Name: "John Doe",
    Vehicle: {
        Details: {
            Make: "Mazda",
            Model: 2010
        },
        Registration: "ABC123",
        ServiceDates: ["01 Jan", "23 Feb", "13 March"]
    },
    WeekDays: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"],
    Children: [{ Name: "Mary", Age: 4, Hobbies: ["Soccer", "Chess", "Swim"] }, { Name: "Jane", Age: 2, Hobbies: ["Tennis", "Movies", "Reading"] }]
};

var map = {
    Vehicle: {
        ServiceDates: false
    },
    Children: [{
        Hobbies: false,
    }]
};

MapJson(obj, map);
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT 2**

Herewith a working sample based on the data you posted in your comment.

```
 var vm = {
    "Type":"PropertyTax",
    "Label":"d",
    "StartDate":"2015-01-01T00:00:00",
    "EndDate":"2015-12-31T00:00:00",
    "Value":0,
    "RegularizationMonth":0,
    "TotalConsumption":null,
    "UnitPrice":null,
    "Active":true,"Products":[{"Selected":false,"Text":"XXX 39","Value":"28"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"ZZZ","Value":"38"}],"ChargeProducts":[{"ProductID":"28","Products":[{"Selected":false,"Text":"XXX 39","Value":"28"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"XXX 41","Value":"8"}]}],
    "map":{"Products":false,"ChargeProducts":[{"Products":false}]}
    };

    var result = MapJson(vm, vm.map);

    console.log("Result: ", result);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. That could have work but i have some case in which FormViewModel have child ViewModel with products array to ignore too ... 
Your solution work only for first level ViewModel. It should be recursive.

Example : Public Class FormViewModel
     Public Property Bar As String
     Public Property ChildViewModel as ChildVM
End Class

Public Class ChildVM
     Public Property ID as Integer
     Public Property Products As List(Of SelectListItem) (=> ToIgnore)
End Class

Comment: Do you want all collections/lists to be excluded, or will there be some that needs to be retained (posted to the server)?

Comment: Not all collections ! Some have to stay alive :)

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a possible solution for dynamically excluding certain JSON data based on a mapping object.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I tried your function :
viewModel.map = {
        Products: false,
        ChargeProducts: [{
            Products: false
        }]
    };
//Later
var data = ko.toJSON(viewModel);       
        data = MapJson(data, viewModel.map);
Which doesn't work. In console.log for data i have Object { 0: "{", 1: """, 2: "T", 3: "y", 4: "p", 5: "e", 6: """, etc ...
I have put a console.log("property : " + prop + " value : " + ret[prop]); in MapJson and it seems it found a property for each character on the original JSON "property : 2976 value : s"
"property : 2977 value : [" etc

Comment: Possible that you can post a sample of your object so that I can test against that?

Comment: Here the partial result of 
var data = ko.toJSON(viewModel);
        console.log(data); : "{"Type":"PropertyTax","Label":"d","StartDate":"2015-01-01T00:00:00","EndDate":"2015-12-31T00:00:00","Value":0,"RegularizationMonth":0,"TotalConsumption":null,"UnitPrice":null,"Active":true,"Products":[{"Selected":false,"Text":"XXX 39","Value":"28"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"ZZZ","Value":"38"}],"ChargeProducts":[{"ProductID":"28","Products":[{"Selected":false,"Text":"XXX 39","Value":"28"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"XXX 41","Value":"8"}]}],"map":{"Products":false,"ChargeProducts":[{"Products":false}]}}"

Comment: Updated the post to include your actual data.  There was a problem with the JSON object itself when I tried to validate it (don't know if that was the cause or merely because of a copy paste).

Comment: Hey, have tested your edit 2. Still not working. We agree that your MapJson function expects a JSON object for obj parameter ? 
If i use your vm object in your edit 2 it's working but it's look like a JS object to me.
Here's a snapshot of my console log for this code : 
var data = ko.toJSON(viewModel);
        console.log(data);
        data = MapJson(data, data.map);
        console.log(data);
http://hpics.li/eab5a91

Comment: Do me a favor.  Just validate your JSON object at http://jsonlint.com/ for me please.  I get a funny feeling there might be something wrong with the object itself.  From the image it seems like the object starts with **"{"Type"** whereas it should be **{"Type"**.

Comment: Pasted my JSON object to your site with " at the begining and at the end it failed. Without " and " it was valid. 
I get this JSON object from Knockout, so i'm wondering where's the problem -_-
Is that not the console that adds those two " ?

Comment: Hi,  eventually got your error replicated on my side. Change the following: instead of using ko.toJSON(viewModel), use **ko.toJS(viewModel)** or **ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel)**  _(Just make sure you have the ko.mapping plugin installed http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html should you use the latter)_

Comment: Okay indeed a JS object is better :] I'll accept your answer. Thanks for your efforts !

Answer (score 0):

If you use KO.Mapping, you can choose certain pieces to ignore.

```
            var mapping = { 'ignore': ["SomeFieldProperty"] };
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, viewModel);
```

This section in the documentation lists all the ways you can manipulate the bindings coming and going, for ko.mapping:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Scroll down to the bottom for the bits on `ignore` as well as topics covering how you can manage bindings and debinding.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I need the binding on arrays because they can be loaded with ajax call.
Moreover your solution require specific code for each different ViewModel (which i have solution with the delete viewModel.PropertyToIgnore when transforming to JSON).

Comment: I might've misunderstood, but I've used the ignore mapping in grabbing a giant object from an ajax call, then using the ignore to ignore binding on arrays inside it that I didn't need observed (bringing down a list of choices, and their options for each choice, the options didn't need binding, since I was just using them as a data source for the choices).   Also, sending them back - it wouldn't render them out.    In the end, I'd move away from ko.mapping -- it's handy as heck, but while it takes a bit more upfront, I've found it easier to just roll my own VM.